# Socket does not work to connect to laptops over WLAN

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

If both scripts run on one device it works just fine, but if the scripts run on separate devices they won't connect even though they are wirelessly connected with the same router.

I am using two Windows devices, one with Windows 10 and one with windows 11.

This is the code for the server:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    SOCKET serverSocket, acceptSocket;
    int port = 55555;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    WORD wVersionReguested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionReguested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr != 0) {
        std::cout << "The Winsock dll not found!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The Winsock dll found!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << std::endl;
    }

    serverSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "socket() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }

    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("192.168.178.49"), &service.sin_addr.s_addr);
    service.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "bind() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "bind() is OK" << std::endl;
    }


    if (listen(serverSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "listen(): Error listening on socket" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

    }
    else {
        std::cout << "listen() is OK. Waiting for connections..." << std::endl;
    }

    acceptSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (acceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Accepted connection" << std::endl;

    char buffer[200];
    int bytecount = recv(acceptSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytecount > 0) {
        std::cout << "Message receved" << buffer << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to receve Message" << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

and that is the client code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    int port = 55555;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    WORD wVersionReguested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionReguested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr != 0) {
        std::cout << "The Winsock dll not found!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The Winsock dll found!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << std::endl;
    }

    clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "socket() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }

    sockaddr_in clientservice;
    clientservice.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("192.168.178.49"), &clientservice.sin_addr.s_addr);
    clientservice.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientservice, sizeof(clientservice)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() is OK" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Client: Can start sending and receiving data..." << std::endl;
    }

    char buffer[200];
    std::cout << "Pleas entere your Message: ";
    std::cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int bytecount = send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytecount > 0) {
        std::cout << "\nMessage was send" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed to send Message: " << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }


    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Pinging the one device from the other although doesn't work. Maybe this is part of the solution.

Comment: You'll probably have to allow the traffic on windows firewall.  If you listen on `0.0.0.0` that will be "all interfaces" and you won't have to hard code / pass IP to listen on (client will still need to know server IP of course).  "Pinging the one device from the other altought doesnt work" Also very possibly a firewall thing, Ping is ICMP and you're using TCP so Ping not working doesn't necessarily indicate anything

Comment: You might have to set something up with windows firewall or netsh. also, in general, your listening ports should be below the 16 bit signed integer limit of about 32767.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have now opend up the port I am using. It still doesnt work. Maybe I should have added that. I had already tried to disable my firewall on both devices. It hasnt worked.

Edit: lowering the portnumber didnt help ether. But thanks for your help.

Comment: There is little doubt that this is some sort of configuration issue, as opposed to a problem with your code.

Comment: In all likelihood you have a networking problem rather than a programming problem. Before trying to write a client and a server in C++, use some off-the-shelf working tested code (such as ncat) to test connectivity. Once you have ruled out networking issues, start debugging your code.

Comment: Yous should improve error handling and print error information to find a root cause of errors. Use WSAGetLastError FormatMessage  to get this details. Refactor code so whole thing is not in `main`.